# Hiding specific tabs on react navigation bottomTabBarNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-android, react-navigation-stack

Imagine I have this structure for my tab bar:

```
const TabBarRoute = {
    Home: HomeStack,
    Orders: OrdersStack,
    Trending: TrendingStack,
    TopSelling: TopSellingStack
}
```

I want to show only three tabs (Orders, Trending, TopSelling) in my bottom tab navigator, How can I achieve it by `react-navigation` version 3.x ?

One idea that come to my mind is that I create a top `stackNavigator` and nest `HomeStack` along with my `bottomTabNavigator` inside of that and set the initial route of the top `stackNavigator` to the `Home`  but problem with this approach is that it doesn't show the tab bar.

Answer (score 2):

This example is using `createBottomTabNavigator`, but I imagine the same rules apply. It requires overriding the `tabBarButtonComponent` with a Custom component which returns null when the user doesn't have access to the given Tab.

```
const Config = {
    allow_locations: true,
    allow_stations: true
}

LocationsStackNavigator.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  return {
    tabBarLabel: 'Locations',
    tabBarTestID: 'locations',
    tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
      <TabBarIcon
        focused={focused}
        name={'md-settings'}/>
    )
  }
};

const MyTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    LocationStackNavigator,
    StationsStackNavigator,
    OrdersStackNavigator,
    SettingsStackNavigator
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarButtonComponent: CustomTabButton
    })
  }
);


class CustomTabButton extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    const {
      onPress,
      onLongPress,
      testID,
      accessibilityLabel,
      ...props
    } = this.props;

    if(testID === 'locations' && !Config.allow_locations) return null;
    if(testID === 'stations' && !Config.allow_stations) return null;

    return <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress} onLongPress={onLongPress} testID={testID} hitSlop={{ left: 15, right: 15, top: 5, bottom: 5 }} accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}>
        <View {...props} />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have dynamic items which they can change according to your situation you can do it in 2 ways :
first, you can declare a component as a parent of your react-navigation component then

1. create a store for your items and set them as @observable and change them whenever you want
2. declare your items as a state of your parent component and pass them to your react navigation

In these two solutions, every time your items change caused your component re-render with new values

Comment: so how can I apply it in the context of `react-navigation` ?

Comment: you can do it like this.    class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
    <Text>Home Screen</Text>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
 {
  Home:this.state.homeVisible ? HomeScreen : <div></div>,
  Details: DetailsScreen,
 },
 {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
 }
);